# What does it mean "Weakest formal language"

Tags: compiler-construction

I am studying the Compiler Design by Alex Aiken. While studying the parser slide, Alex said that "Regular language is the weakest formal language". [image]

[From Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TJGgfz6te8&list=PLsQE6uhzFRdxifNKnwkbFAGvdACeEqKrK&index=17)

Can anyone please clarify this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

He probably means it's at the bottom of the [Chomsky Heirarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#summary). It means that with a device that can only solve regular problems (like regular expression matching), you could never hope to emulate a more complex language or ever run general software like a proper computer can. The highest level (in the chart), is much more powerful than 'regular' and called 'recursively enumerable'. Describes the class of problems solvable via 'turing machine' or any modern computer processor.

Edit: Just watched the video, and that is definitely what he is alluding to, but, if he's got a more practical angle. He's not teaching you CS theory (although it would help to learn the theory, which I linked to above).

His angle is more practical, he's just telling you Regular is the least powerful of these in terms of power for compiling code. Here are the formal languages he's comparing:

- Recursively enumerable
- Context Free
- Context Sensitive
- Regular

Regular is the least powerful and the others are more powerful. He goes on to explain the limitations of regular languages with the rest of the video.